# Azure how to process DeviceClient.CompleteAsync(Message)

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

First a brief background-

I'm trying out the tutorial found [HERE](https://microsoft.hackster.io/en-US/ediwang/azure-remote-controlled-light-with-windows-10-iot-core-75df20). I've scaled down the application to switch an ellipse either red or green over the internet using Azure IOT hub. So the idea is to change the ellipse from an UWP on my Windows Phone (or Desktop as this is UWP it doesn't matter).

I'm using Device Explorer as used in the tutorial to send message/command to the app to switch the color of the ellipse. Upon completion of the command Device Explorer displays a feedback status as follows -

`Message Feedback status: "Success", Description: "Success"`

My guess is after completing every command the app is sending a status using

`await DeviceClient.CompleteAsync(Message)`

But how is Device Explorer receiving it? I can't find the answer after crawling the web nor there is any documentation regarding this matter.

To recreate the problem create an UWP app using the following XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="YourAppName.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Ellipse x:Name="LED"
                     Fill="LightGray"
                     Stroke="White"
                     Width="100"
                     Height="100"
                     Margin="10"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="onBtn" 
                Content="On/Off" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="140,498,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="feedbackTxt" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Margin="15,148,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 Text="Status" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="331"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

and then add the following code in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Message = Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message;


namespace YourAppName
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage
    {

        private readonly SolidColorBrush _redBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
        private readonly SolidColorBrush _grayBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGray);
        private readonly SolidColorBrush _greenBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DeviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(IotHubUri, 
            new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(DeviceId, DeviceKey));
            Loaded += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                // send device connected message
                await SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync();

                // receive remote light control events
                await ReceiveCloudToDeviceMessageAsync();
            };
        }

        #region Azure IoT Hub Settings

        private DeviceClient DeviceClient { get; set; }

        private string IotHubUri { get; } = "Your HOST Name";

        private string DeviceKey { get; } = "Your Device Key";

        private static string DeviceId => "Your Device ID";

        #endregion

        public async Task SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var telemetryDataPoint = new
                {
                    deviceId = DeviceId,
                    message = "Hello"
                };
                var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryDataPoint);
                var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));

                await DeviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
                Debug.WriteLine("{0} > Sending message: {1}", DateTime.Now, messageString);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public async Task ReceiveCloudToDeviceMessageAsync()
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("\nReceiving cloud to device messages from service");

            while (true)
            {
                var receivedMessage = await DeviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
                if (receivedMessage == null) continue;

                var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes());


                if (msg == "on")
                {
                    LED.Fill = _greenBrush;
                    await DeviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
                    feedbackTxt.Text = msg;
                }

                if (msg == "off")
                {
                    LED.Fill = _redBrush;
                    await DeviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
                    feedbackTxt.Text = msg;
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Open `project.json` file and replace with the following-

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Azure.Devices": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client": "1.0.22",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

And finally Right click on the project and add a reference to `Windows IOT Extension`

Replace the placeholders with your credentials and you will be able to do this-

Turn On
[image: Turn ON]

Turn Off

[image: Turn Off]

How is Device Explorer receiving the highlighted `Message Feedback status` ?

[image]

My use case is- I would like to confirm that the command I have sent is executed successfully(lets say turn on a light) and only then display a message telling the user its done.

Help anyone?

In reply to Junas

[image]

Nothing really happens... May be I get the using statement wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation shows how to send cloud-to-device messages *and* receive messages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d

I've compiled the example here:

```
private static ServiceClient;
private static string connectionString = "{iot hub connection string}";

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Send Cloud-to-Device message\n");
    serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

    ReceiveFeedbackAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to send a C2D message.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    SendCloudToDeviceMessageAsync().Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private async static Task SendCloudToDeviceMessageAsync()
{
    var commandMessage = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Cloud to device message."));
    commandMessage.Ack = DeliveryAcknowledgement.Full;
    await serviceClient.SendAsync("myFirstDevice", commandMessage);
}

private async static void ReceiveFeedbackAsync()
{
    var feedbackReceiver = serviceClient.GetFeedbackReceiver();

    Console.WriteLine("\nReceiving c2d feedback from service");
    while (true)
    {
        var feedbackBatch = await feedbackReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
        if (feedbackBatch == null) continue;

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("Received feedback: {0}", string.Join(", ", feedbackBatch.Records.Select(f => f.StatusCode)));
        Console.ResetColor();

        await feedbackReceiver.CompleteAsync(feedbackBatch);
    }
}
```

In short, you have to:

1. Create a ServiceClient (and cache it)
2. Start receiving feedback in the background with a feedback receiver
3. Send your message and set Ack to Full to request feedback

Comment: I cant get it to work. Can you Upload the solution somewhere please? Dont forget to remove your credentials

Comment: Actually I just took this from the official documentation, I don't really have time now to set it up :(